# How to install Ruby via rvm1-capistrano3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm-capistrano, capistrano3

I want to install rvm via rvm1-capistrano. Every time I run the task it tells me that `Ruby [version] is not installed`. Which is weird because I already know its not installed, and this is why I'm running the task: To install it. Why is this?

This is a vanilla out of the box installation. I've not changed anything. I added the following:

set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p353' # to deploy.rb, same error w/without
set :pty, true # deploy.rb
require 'rvm1/capistrano3' # to Capfile

Per others' recommendation, I added a `.ruby-version` to the root of my app with `2.0.0` as contents.

What am I not understanding correctly? Why would the task charged with installing ruby tell me ruby is not installed?

```
DEBUG [09203819] Command: cd ~/apps/simpleblog/releases/20140121174439 && /usr/bin/env /tmp/simpleblog/rvm-auto.sh rvm install .
DEBUG [09203819]    ruby-2.0.0-p353 is not installed.
DEBUG [09203819]    
DEBUG [09203819]    To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353'
DEBUG [09203819]    
DEBUG [09203819]    Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
DEBUG [09203819]    
DEBUG [09203819]    No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/13.10/x86_64/system.
DEBUG [09203819]    
DEBUG [09203819]    Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
DEBUG [09203819]    
DEBUG [09203819]    RVM does not have prediction for required space for system, assuming 150MB should be enough, let us know if it was not.
DEBUG [09203819]    
DEBUG [09203819]    Either the ruby interpreter is unknown or there was an error!.
DEBUG [09203819]
```

Comment: sounds like a bug, update rvm on the server and if it still fails open an issue here with details: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues